# New Apache's version in repositories

Tags: apache2, repository, official-repositories

Does anyone has a time frame for an update in Apache's version for repositories/official-repositories?

Ubuntu server is working like a charm and wouldn't like to switch to manual installation for Apache due to PCIDSS flags. Currently ver 2.2.22 (2.2.22-1ubuntu1.4) is distributed from repositories and ASVs find this to be vulnerable although security patches are applied.

Answer (score 0):

For various reasons, software already in the main repos aren't updated to a new upstream version unless there are security bugs in the current versions (CVE, denial-of-service, etc.). If there is a published vulnerability for this version, you can file a bug [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/apache2), and someone may work on a security update.

Comment: I know that it is not a bug and Ubuntu has released a security patch for CVE-2012-0883 as an example. The problem here is that ASVs get the Apache version and no matter if its patched or not they still give a flag.

Comment: Ah, so they are going solely based on the upstream version (the 2.22.22 part)?

Comment: Yes, it seems like that